# variable power supply (0V/5V/7V/10V/17V) without using potentiometer

Tags: power-supply

How can I design a variable power supply that will give an output of 0V/5V/7V/10V/17V without using a potentiometer? I don't know much to do because my professor didn't taught us about this. If you can help me or give me the schematic diagram for this, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use a switch?

Comment: I literally don't know how to use a switch right now because my professor is out of his mind and he suddenly wanted us to make this prototype. I understand the components and their functions but I can't design/simulate it.

Comment: Use N different resistors and N positions rotary switch or jumpers instead of potentiometer.

Comment: Could you put up a circuit of a variable power supply that you are familiar with and can understand?

Comment: Right now I can only understand up to the rectifier(bridge) part. That's it

Comment: @PauloDelaPeña Do you understand, that right now only you see the schematics and the rectifier that you are talking about? Not us?

Comment: Your instructor would not assign a variable power supply without talking about regulation.  We can not help you unless you help yourself.  We guess poorly or get bored.

Comment: If I said LM317.  Would you recognize it?

Comment: yes i can recognize that. @StainlessSteelRat

Comment: Your question isn't very coherent.  Spehro Pefhany has given you one answer, but it may be above the limits of what you have learned.  Is it possible that you are to design an unregulated power supply using a transformer with multiple outputs?  That would be much closer to the level of knowledge that you seem to have, given that you say you don't even know how to use a switch.

Comment: So assuming one of your feedback resistors is constant.  Work out the resistance to get your 5V.  Repeat for 7V, etc.  Use a multiposition switch to select appropriate resistors to get voltages.  0V tell him to turn off power.  As JRE says: Spehro Pefhany has given you the process.

Comment: I can understand only up to the single output but for multiple outputs and without using a potentiometer I am having a problem. My instructor is out of his mind.

Comment: ROFL  If it was easy, there is no point to learning.  You only have one output.  R1 = constant.  Use a switch to select different resistors R2 on adjustment pin to select your different voltages.  You could do it this way http://www.eleccircuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/lm317-linear-power-supply-regulator-15v3v45v5v6v9v_15a.jpg with a rotary switch or discrete resistors http://us1.webpublications.com.au/static/images/articles/i1104/110498_3lo.jpg .

Comment: I've been on that subject for 2 week so yeah that's my knowledge after 2 weeks. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're using a regulator with a reference voltage of 1.25V. You can switch the *input* to a divider (using selector switch with the common connected to the output voltage) such that the output is 1.250V with output voltages of 5/7/10/17. For 0V out, I suggest the user unplug the supply (or add a switch contact to do that).

For example, if you have a resistor from the feedback input terminal of 200\$\Omega\$ then it would draw 6.25mA, and the required resistor values would be:

R5V: (5-1.25) /6.25 = 600\$\Omega\$

R7V: (7-5) /6.25 = 320\$\Omega\$

R10V: (10-7) / 6.25 = 480\$\Omega\$

R17V: (17-10) / 6.25 = 1.12K\$\Omega\$

Note that if your switch is break-before-make (which is normal), the output voltage will spike during the switch operation so it could destroy whatever is connected to the output.

There is a way to mitigate this potential problem, but I'll leave that for later.